# Crear objeto a partir del nombre de clase con parámetros usando reflección en Qt creator c++

Tags: c++, qt, reflection, reflexión

Tengo el siguiente código [php](/questions/tagged/php):

```
$pdf="pdf3";
$xml="xml3";
$arreglo="arreglo3";
$clases=array('Validacion1','Validacion2');
$validaciones=array();
foreach ($clases as $nombre_clase){
    include_once($nombre_clase.'.php');
    if(class_exists($nombre_clase,false)) {
        $objetoValidacion = new $nombre_clase($pdf,$xml,$arreglo);
        $validaciones[$nombre_clase]=$objetoValidacion;
    }
}
```

y tengo eso mismo en [java](/questions/tagged/java):

```
String pdf="pdf",xml="xml";
String []arreglo={"arreglo"};
String []clases={"com.Validacion1","com.Validacion2"};
Map<String,ValidacionGenerica> validaciones=new HashMap<String,ValidacionGenerica>();
for (int i = 0; i < clases.length; i++) {
  try {
      Class<?> clase=Class.forName(clases[i]);
      Constructor<?> ctor=clase.getConstructor(String.class,String.class,String[].class);
      Object objetoValidacion=ctor.newInstance(pdf,xml,arreglo);
      validaciones.put(clases[i],(ValidacionGenerica)objetoValidacion);
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Como puedo hacer esto mismo en **Qt Creator** [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)? Es decir crear objetos a partir del nombre de la clase y pasando 3 argumentos al constructor.

Con esto ya podre agregarlos al arreglo([php](/questions/tagged/php)) o mapa ([java](/questions/tagged/java)). Tengo entendido que se usa la clase `QMetaType` pero la [documentación](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html) que encontré no me ayuda mucho con el paso de parámetros al constructor o no le entiendo.

Este es mi código pero tengo errores:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <validaciongenerica.h>
#include <validacion1.h>
#include <validacion2.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <QMetaType>
using namespace std;
typedef pair<string, ValidacionGenerica> nombre_valor;
int main()
{
    string clases[]={"Validacion1","Validacion2"};
    int tamano_clases = sizeof(clases)/sizeof(clases[0]);
    map<string,ValidacionGenerica>  validaciones();
    for (int i = 0; i < tamano_clases ; i++) {
        int id = QMetaType::type(clases[i]);//error 1
        if (id != 0) {
            ValidacionGenerica *myClassPtr = QMetaType::construct(id);//error 2
            validaciones().insert(nombre_valor(clases[i],*myClassPtr));
        }
    }
}
```

Este es uno:

```
 no matching function for call to 'QMetaType::type(std::string&)'
             int id = QMetaType::type(clases[i]);
                                               ^
```

y este el otro:

```
cannot call member function 'void* QMetaType::construct(void*, const void*) const' without object
             ValidacionGenerica *myClassPtr = QMetaType::construct(id);
                                                                     ^
```

Comment: ¿Las clases `Validacion1` y `Validacion2` heredan de `QObject`? Si no es así no  va a funcionar nunca. No solo es que hereden... también han de incluir la macro `Q_OBJECT`. Dado que no indicas su declaración no es posible conocer este dato.

Comment: Ok, gracias, eso no lo sabia lo colocaré. Pregunta: ¿si ValidacionGenerica hereda de QObject y, Validacion1 y Validacion2 heredan de ValidacionGenerica es suficiente con eso?? o ?tengo que colocar la herencia multiple para que ambas clases hereden de ValidacionGenerica y QObject?.
Aún así mi duda principal sigue siendo como pasar los argumentos al constructor.
Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si `ValidacionGenerica` hereda de `QObject` (herencia pública), cualquier clase que herede de `ValidacionGenerica` conseguirá la herencia de `QObject`. La macro `Q_OBJECT`, en cambio, ha de estar presente en cada clase para que los metadatos funcionen correctamente.

Answer (score 3):

> no matching function for call to 'QMetaType::type(std::string&)'

`classes` debería ser un vector de `QString` en vez de `std::string`. Qt proporciona su propia clase para la gestión de cadenas y te obliga a usarla para interactuar con las librerías de Qt.

El segundo error puede ser un efecto colateral del primero, ya que la estructura parece ser la correcta.

Eso sí, no hay que olvidar que `QMetaType::construct` devuelve un puntero genérico `void*`. La forma correcta de convertir ese puntero en el tipo que tu esperas es usando `static_cast`:

```
ValidacionGenerica *myClassPtr
  = static_cast<ValidacionGenerica*>(QMetaType::construct(id));
```

Y ya, revisando un poco más a fondo tu código me he encontrado con esto:

```
map<string,ValidacionGenerica>  validaciones();
```

si `validaciones` es un mapa que almacena instancias de `ValidacionGenerica` por valor entonces vas a perder toda la potencia del polimorfismo. Me explico:

```
struct Base
{
  virtual void func()
  { std::cout << "Base::func()" << std::endl; }
};

struct Derivada1 : public Base
{
  void func() override
  { std::cout << "Derivada1::func()" << std::endl; }
};

struct Derivada2 : public Base
{
  void func() override
  { std::cout << "Derivada2::func()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Base> datos;
  datos.push_back(Base());
  datos.push_back(Derivada1());
  datos.push_back(Derivada2());

  for( auto &dato : datos )
    dato.func();
}
```

Este programa va a imprimir lo siguiente:

```
Base::func()
Base::func()
Base::func()
```

¿Por qué? Porque el vector almacena objetos por valor, luego al insertar un nuevo elemento estaremos realizando una copia del mismo... bueno, más o menos, ya que se va a realizar una copia de `Base` en vez de una copia de `Derivada1` o de `Derivada2`. Si decoramos un poco más el código se verá mejor:

```
struct Base
{
  Base()
  { std::cout << "Base::Base()" << std::endl; }

  Base(const Base&)
  { std::cout << "Base::Base(const Base&)" << std::endl; }

  virtual ~Base()
  { }

  virtual void func()
  { std::cout << "Base::func()" << std::endl; }
};

struct Derivada1 : public Base
{
  Derivada1()
  { std::cout << "Derivada1::Derivada1()" << std::endl; }

  Derivada1(const Derivada1 &)
  { std::cout << "Derivada1::Derivada1(const Derivada1&)" << std::endl; }

  virtual ~Derivada1()
  { }

  void func() override
  { std::cout << "Derivada1::func()" << std::endl; }
};

struct Derivada2 : public Base
{
  Derivada2()
  { std::cout << "Derivada2::Derivada2()" << std::endl; }

  Derivada2(const Derivada2 &)
  { std::cout << "Derivada2::Derivada2(const Derivada2&)" << std::endl; }

  virtual ~Derivada2()
  { }

  void func() override
  { std::cout << "Derivada2::func()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Base> datos;

  std::cout << "1er elemento" << std::endl;
  datos.push_back(Base());

  std::cout << std::endl << "2o elemento" << std::endl;
  datos.push_back(Derivada1());

  std::cout << std::endl << "3er elemento" << std::endl;
  datos.push_back(Derivada2());

  std::cout << std::endl << "llamada a func" << std::endl;
  for( auto &dato : datos )
    dato.func();
}
```

La salida del programa será ahora:

```
1er elemento
Base::Base()
Base::Base(const Base&)

2o elemento
Base::Base()
Derivada1::Derivada1()
Base::Base(const Base&)
Base::Base(const Base&)

3er elemento
Base::Base()
Derivada2::Derivada2()
Base::Base(const Base&)
Base::Base(const Base&)
Base::Base(const Base&)

llamada a func
Base::func()
Base::func()
Base::func()
```

Como ves, al insertar los elementos en el vector se invoca al constructor copia de `Base` y esto es así simplemente porque el vector es de elementos de tipo `Base`. Al construir un nuevo objeto de tipo `Base` se pierde el tipo original y con ello toda la lógica asociada a dicho tipo.

**Inciso:** Al añadir el primer elemento se llama una vez al constructor copia de `Base`, al añadir el segundo elemento se llama dos veces y la secuencia continúa al añadir el tercer elemento. Esto es porque el vector, al redimensionarse, tiene que copiar los objetos del vector a la nueva posición de memoria. Esto puede evitarse si se reserva previamente la memoria necesaria para el vector usando `datos.reserve(X)`, donde `X` es el número de elementos que va a almacenar el contenedor.

Para evitar este problema hay que manejar obligatoriamente punteros:

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<Base*> datos;

  std::cout << "1er elemento" << std::endl;
  datos.push_back(new Base());

  std::cout << std::endl << "2o elemento" << std::endl;
  datos.push_back(new Derivada1());

  std::cout << std::endl << "3er elemento" << std::endl;
  datos.push_back(new Derivada2());

  std::cout << std::endl << "llamada a func" << std::endl;
  for( auto dato : datos )
    dato->func();

  // Para liberar la memoria
  std::for_each(datos.begin(),datos.end(),std::default_delete<Base>());
}
```

Salida:

```
1er elemento
Base::Base()

2o elemento
Base::Base()
Derivada1::Derivada1()

3er elemento
Base::Base()
Derivada2::Derivada2()

llamada a func
Base::func()
Derivada1::func()
Derivada2::func()
```

---

Añadido a raiz del siguiente comentario:

> He tratado de implementar de nuevo siguiendo estas explicaciones, pero aún así no funciona. Parece que el problema no es tanto de conceptos de herencia y polimorfismo de c++. Mas bien es con el runtime de QT y el funcionamiento de las clases de metadatos como QMetaType, QMetaObject, QObject, etc. Gracias de todos modos.

Vamos a realizar un ejemplo de prueba.

Lo primero es implementar la clase base. En este caso voy a implementar un cascarón básico que cumple con las necesidades mínimas de la prueba. Dispone de un método virtual para verificar que se ha creado el objeto correcto. Nota que no he usado la macro `Q_OBJECT` ya que para el ejemplo no es necesario.

**ValidacionGenerica**

```
#include <QObject>

class ValidacionGenerica
{
  public:
    ValidacionGenerica() = default;
    ValidacionGenerica(const ValidacionGenerica&) = default;

    virtual ~ValidacionGenerica()
    { }

    virtual void test() = 0;
};
```

Ahora las clases específicas.

Lo más destacado de estas dos implementaciones es el uso de Q_DECLARE_TYPE para registrar el tipo en los metadatos.

**Validacion1**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ValidacionGenerica.hh"

class Validacion1 : public ValidacionGenerica
{
  public:

    Validacion1() = default;
    Validacion1(const Validacion1&) = default;

    void test() override
    { std::cout << "Validacion1" << std::endl; }
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Validacion1);
```

**Validacion2**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ValidacionGenerica.hh"

class Validacion2 : public ValidacionGenerica
{
  public:

    Validacion2() = default;
    Validacion2(const Validacion2&) = default;

    void test() override
    { std::cout << "Validacion2" << std::endl; }
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Validacion2);
```

Y ahora el main:

**main**

```
int main()
{
  qRegisterMetaType<Validacion1>("Validacion1");
  qRegisterMetaType<Validacion2>("Validacion2");

  std::vector<string> classes {"Validacion1","Validacion2"};

  map<string,ValidacionGenerica*>  validaciones;
  for( auto currClass : classes)
  {
    int id = QMetaType::type(currClass.c_str());
    if (id != 0)
    {
      void* ptr = QMetaType::create(id);
      ValidacionGenerica *myClassPtr = static_cast<ValidacionGenerica*>(ptr);//error 2
      validaciones.insert(std::make_pair(currClass,myClassPtr));
      myClassPtr->test();
    }
  }

}
```

Algunos detalles de esta función:

- `qRegisterMetaType` permite asociar un nombre a cada clase de metadatos. Es necesario para que `QMetaType` funcione correctamente.
- `validaciones` no puede ser un mapa que almacene `ValidacionGenerica` por valor porque si no se pierde la herencia.
- `QMetaType::construct` es una función de bajo nivel. Lo recomendable es llamar a `QMetaType::create`, por lo menos en versiones modernas de Qt.
- Los templates son herramientas muy potentes y hay que saber usarlos. Fíjate que no hace falta definir el tipo `nombre_valor` para crear un `pair`. Basta con llamar al template `std::make_pair` y el solito suele deducir los tipos correctamente.

Con el código que te he puesto, la salida del programa es la siguiente:

```
Validacion1
Validacion2
```

Un saludo.

Comment: He tratado de implementar de nuevo siguiendo estas explicaciones, pero aún así no funciona. Parece que el problema no es tanto de conceptos de herencia y polimorfismo de c++. Mas bien es con el runtime de QT y el funcionamiento de las clases de metadatos como QMetaType, QMetaObject, QObject, etc. Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta que la he actualizado. Un saludo

Comment: Con la actualización que me has dado me ha funcionado, pero debo comentar que he hecho un par de modificaciones para lograrlo.
La 1ra es que elimine la instrucción Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Validacion1); ya que leí que en la versión de QT 5 ya no es necesaria. Y aunque parece que funciona en ambos casos, cuando la coloco el IDE me marca una especie de warning.
Lo otro que hice y creo que es lo mas importante fue colocar en mi archivo .pro la siguiente linea CONFIG += c++11 para que funcionara la declaración del vector std::vector<std::string> clases = {"Validacion1","Validacion2"}; y sin eso truena

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Cierto. Desde hace un tiempo por defecto uso sintaxis propia de al menos C++11. Siento no haberlo indicado

Comment: Oye una ultima pregunta, la clase se crea así `void* clase = QMetaType::create(id);` y mi pregunta es ¿Como podría pasarle parámetros al constructor?

Comment: La pregunta inicial ya está respondida. Lo suyo es que crees una nueva pregunta. Así mantenemos el contenido debidamente organizado y limpio.

Comment: Bueno es que la pregunta inicial dice `Con parametros` por eso pense que no se debía crear un tema nuevo

Comment: Si reescribo la pregunta entonces se perderá el feedback que actualmente tiene. Si añado nuevo contenido da la sensación de que va a ser demasiado larga e inconexa. También puedes esperar por si alguien da una respuesta concreta en ese aspecto.